# .bss section generates segment fault and

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm using Jon Bartlett's "Programming from the Ground Up" to learn assembler.  My environment is x86-64 on Linux.

My file is:

```
.code32

.section .data

.section .text

# if I uncomment these lines, compile, I get a segfault
#.section .bss
#       .lcomm buff, 500

.globl _start

_start:
        pushl $97
        call toUppercase
        addl $4,%esp

        movl %eax, %ebx
exit:
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80


# args: ch
#       ch -- character to upper case
#
# ret:  uppercase version of ch, untouched if not a character
.type toUppercase,@function
toUppercase:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        movl 8(%ebp),%eax
        cmpl $97, %eax
        jl toUppercase_return
        cmpl $122, %eax
        jg toUppercase_return
        subl $32, %eax
toUppercase_return:
        movl %ebp, %esp
        popl %ebp
        ret
```

Which I compile using

```
gcc -m32 -g file.s -o file
```

If I uncomment the lines in the file around .section .bss  I get segment faults when running the program, otherwise it works fine.  Also,  if I uncomment said lines, I can no longer open the program in gdbtui even though it compiles and links.  Commented out, it opens just fine in gdbtui.

I finally moved .bss before .text and it compiles and works while also loading in the debugger.  So my question has become, why must the .bss section come before the .text section to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.section .bss` overwrites the former `.section .text`. Every following code 
will be interpreted as .BSS-data and not as .TEXT-code. You should put your .bss-block to a place where it can't disturb other sections e.g. to the end of the script.

Comment: Also note `.lcomm` can be in any section because it automatically allocates in `.bss`. See the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Lcomm.html).